# Dynamic Icon loading in LWC doesn't work

Tags: lightning-web-components, svg, public-reactive-properties

I am using the `progress-ring` **LWC** component from https://github.com/texei/progress-ring and fail to make the SLDS SVG Icon displayed dynamic work:

**Usage:**

```
<c-progress-ring ... icon="symbols.svg#warning"></c-progress-ring>
```

**HTML:**

```
<template if:true={icon}>
    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility" title={state}>
        <svg class="slds-icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/{icon}"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">{state}</span>
    </span>
</template>
```

**JS:**

import { LightningElement, api, track } from "lwc";

```
export default class ProgressRing extends LightningElement {
    @api min;
    @api max;
    @api icon;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution of my component :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it work using the `<lighting-icon>` tag.

```
<template if:true={icon}>
    <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size="x-small" ></lightning-icon>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the `<lightning-icon>` tag? Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/example).

For your code, the HTML should look something like this: (you should modify the component call a little bit, so your text for "icon" satisfies the specification (i.e. "action:approval")

```
<template if:true={icon}>
    <lightning-icon icon-name={icon} alternative-text={state}></lightning-icon>
</template>
```

Comment: LWC utility icons are showing very slow (after 2sec) after adding dynamically...
Any solution to reduce delay.

<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>